# SAPUI5 oData.V2 How to invoke a function after everything in a batch request is done?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have an issue while making an SAPUI5 odata V2 batch request :

```
           var that = this;
            var oServiceModel = that.getModel("oServiceModel");
                odataMod = this.getModel("Service");
            odataMod.setUseBatch(true);
            var aData = oServiceModel.getData();
            var stupidService = _.filter(aData, function (ae) {
                return ae.Info === "-N/A";
            });
             var i = 0 ; 
            _.forEach(stupidService, function (sap) {
                oGlobalBusyDialog.setText("Deleting service :" + sap.ObjectID);
                oGlobalBusyDialog.setTitle("Deleting Service");
                oGlobalBusyDialog.open();
                that.removeService(sap).then(function () {
                    if (i === 615) {
                        oGlobalBusyDialog.close();
                    }
                }).catch(function () {});
            });
```

my Delete function is like this:

```
removeService: function (service) {


    var that = this;
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            odataMod.remove('/ProjectTaskServiceCollection(\'' + service.ObjectID + '\')/', {
                success: function (oData) {
                    resolve(oData);
                },
                error: function (oResult) {
                    that.handleError(oResult);
                    oGlobalBusyDialog.close();
                    reject(oResult);
                }
            });
        });
```

What's happening ,is that if I'm trying to delete 500 entry, and if 200 entry cannot be deleted, the error message gets displayed 200 times

How to make it in a way to only display the error message once ?

Also, I want to turn off the batch request once everything is done `odataMod.setUseBatch(false`); how to do it ?

*EDIT: *

I've manage to do :

```
var aDeffGroup = odataMod.getDeferredGroups();
//add your deffered group
aDeffGroup.push("deletionGroup");
for (var s = 0; s < 5; s++) {
    odataMod.remove('/ProjectTaskServiceCollection(\'' + stupidService[s].ObjectID + '\')/', {
        //pass groupid to remove method.
        groupId: "deletionGroup"
    });
}

odataMod.submitChanges({
    // your deffered group id
    groupId: "deletionGroup",
    success: function() {
        //Get message model data from Core and it contains all errors
        // Use this data to show in dialog or in a popover or set this to your local model see below code
        var aErrorData = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().getMessageModel();
        console.log(aErrorData);
    }
});
```

yet stills my `console.log(aErrorData);` still prints multiple error message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing individual deletion odata calls. Add these all remove methods in a single group, then call `odatamod.submitChanges()` method.

Example:

```
//get all deffered groups
    var aDeffGroup = odataMod.getDeferredGroups();

//add your deffered group
    aDeffGroup.push("deletionGroup");

//set it back again to odatamodel
    odataMod.setDeferredGroups(aDeffGroup);

    odataMod.remove('/ProjectTaskServiceCollection(\'' + service.ObjectID + '\')/', {
 //pass groupid to remove method.
         groupId: "deletionGroup"});
     odataMod.submitChanges({
     // your deffered group id
     groupId:"deletionGroup",
     success: function() {
       //Get message model data from Core and it contains all errors
       // Use this data to show in dialog or in a popover or set this to your local model see below code
      var aErrorData = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().getMessageModel();

   });
```

Comment: Hey Saddam Hussein, thank you, but when I do console.log(aErrorData ), it still prints 200 times in my console any idea why ?
btw you have a typo it's setDeferedGroup not setDefferedGroup

Comment: I've edited my question to show you what I've tried so far

Comment: sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().getMessageModel() this is a message model which returns array of errors, either you display one error or display whole data in popover control.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand perfectly how the batch request works, your help was very appreciated

Comment: Also, I've encountered a problem concerning the deferred group ID and I solve it but adding : odataMod.setDeferredGroups(aDeffGroup); just after pushing it, so I would recommend to edit your code and add odataMod.setDeferredGroups(aDeffGroup);